# SpringForm with Jquery Validation not working

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jquery-validate

i am trying to validate a spring mvc form having spring tags with Jquery but this validation isn't working,need urgent help. The following JS files are being used.

On inspection i am able to see that the values are getting passed by the element id's but the validation and the error messages are not
    working. Please help as i am not very well versed with Jquery. Your help would be much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm()
    {
        $("#savelogin").validate({      
            rules:
            { 
                UName: 
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 40
                },
                pwd:
                { 
                    equired: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 40
                }
            },
            messages:
            {
                UName:
                {
                    required: "username is required!",
                    minlength: "username must be at least 6 characters long"
                },
                pwd:
                {
                    required: "Please enter a password",
                    minlength: "Password must be at least 6 characters long"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form)
            {
                form.submit();
            }
        });  
    }
</script> 

<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <form:form commandName="userLogin" id="savelogin">
        <fieldset>
            <c:url value="/Registration.do" var="url"/>
            <a href="<c:out value='${url}'/>">New User:Register</a>
            <div>
                <form:label path="userRegistration.userName" ><spring:message code="label.username"/>   </form:label>
                <form:input path ="userRegistration.userName" autocomplete="on" id="UName" />
                <form:errors path="userRegistration.userName"></form:errors> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <form:label path="userRegistration.password"><spring:message code="label.password"/></form:label>
                <form:password path="userRegistration.password"   id="pwd"/>
                <form:errors path="userRegistration.password"></form:errors>
            </div>

            <div>      
                <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.login"/>" name="loginUser" id="submit" onclick="submitForm();"/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form:form>
</body>
```

---

```
   $(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#savelogin").validate({      
       rules:
       { 
          UName: 
         {
             required: true,
             minlength: 6,
             maxlength: 40
         },
         pwd:
         { 
             equired: true,
             minlength: 6,
             maxlength: 40
         }
     },
     messages:
     {
         UName:
         {
             required: "username is required!",
             minlength: "username must be at least 6 characters long"
         },
         pwd:
         {
             required: "Please enter a password",
             minlength: "Password must be at least 6 characters long"
         }
     },
     submitHandler: function(form)
     {
         form.submit();
     }
 });
```

});

I tried with this but nothing happened. Please check and help.

Answer (score 4):

Your issues are as follows:

1) The `.validate()` method is the *initialization* of the plugin and only needs to be called *one time*.  Place it inside a DOM ready event handler.

2)  The rules are only assigned by `name` attribute, not `id`.  Since your names contain dots, you must enclose them in quotes.  See:  [jqueryvalidation.org/reference/](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/)

3)  You misspelled `required` as `equired` on your password field.

4)  If your `submitHandler` only contains `form.submit()`, then you don't need it at all.  This is the default behavior, so you only need to use the `submitHandler` callback if you want to do something else upon a valid form.

**Documentation:**  [jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  // <-- enclose your code in a DOM ready handler

    $("#savelogin").validate({
        rules: {
            "userRegistration.userName": { // <-- assign by field name and use quotes
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 40
            },
            "userRegistration.password": {
                required: true,  // <-- this rule was misspelled 'equired'
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 40
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "userRegistration.userName": {
                required: "username is required!",
                minlength: "username must be at least 6 characters long"
            },
            "userRegistration.password": {
                required: "Please enter a password",
                minlength: "Password must be at least 6 characters long"
            }
        }
        /*, // submitHandler is not needed for this case
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();  // <-- this is the default
        }
        */
    });

});

</script>
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/kCDDK/**

Comment: @ShivayanMukherjee, "Accept" means to click the green checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @Sparky Hi, i also had this problem  why using input id in validate method is not working?

Comment: @Sanshayan, because you **MUST** only use the `name` within the `.validate()` method.  Refer to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing validation code inside function will not work you need to write code inside document.ready not inside function.

Or call function on body load.

All You need to do is replace your script tag with below code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $("#savelogin").validate({      
            rules:
            { 
                UName: 
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 40
                },
                pwd:
                { 
                    equired: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 40
                }
            },
            messages:
            {
                UName:
                {
                    required: "username is required!",
                    minlength: "username must be at least 6 characters long"
                },
                pwd:
                {
                    required: "Please enter a password",
                    minlength: "Password must be at least 6 characters long"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form)
            {
                form.submit();
            }
        });  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i tried with your solution but didn't get the expected result.. posted above is the modified code.

Comment: have posted the renedered html,please check.

Comment: @ShivayanMukherjee okay jQuery.validate plugin get elements as per tag name so you need to replace rules and message selector to tag name like `userRegistration.userName` instead of `UName`

Comment: well i tried putting in userRegistration.userName  but error was thrown right away. What i see is,the <form:input path=""> tag renders as <input id="UName" class="error" type="text" autocomplete="on" value="" name="userRegistration.userName"> if u mention an id expliciltly. Here id is not important because Jquery takes the attribute 'name' into consideration. So here i find Jquery is unable to recognise the 'dot(.)' in name="userRegistration.userName". Though i am not sure but i feel this is what is actually happening because in my other application where the name is straight its working

Comment: alright. So is there a way to fix this because i can't alter the name as the element is being accessed from its parent bean.